# How do I use Parse.com's push notification feature for a change in PFObjects?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

Can I use Parse.com’s push notification feature to send an array of PFObjects to the user when either a new one is added, or an existing one is deleted?? If so, how should I go about it? I’m writing an app for iOS. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
After doing a bit of searching,  I see I have to use the cloud code aftersave() method, and then send a push notification through JavaScript.

If anyone could provide examples of how to go about it, that would be great. In the meantime I'm going through the docs. Thanks again all.

Comment: Push notifications can only contain a message, not an array of PFObjects. Are you asking if you can send a message to a device when one of your columns in Parse is updates?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I am. I did a bit of searching, and I see I have to use the cloud code aftersave() method, and then send a push notification through JavaScript (https://www.parse.com/questions/push-notification-on-data-browser-data-change). Sounds quite complicated, will start reading through it all tomorrow. Any further help would also be appreciated :)

Comment: I'll try to put together a response later today. In my experience, configuring everything was the most tedious part. The coding wasn't too bad.

Comment: Hey Todd, do you still think you could put up a response?

Comment: Did that help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) really contains everything you need to get started. Writing the code that sends the actual notification is only a small part of the whole process that is required to send push notifications. Here are the steps required:

1. Create an SSL Certificate: create the cert via Apple Developer Center then export it with Keychain Application
2. Create Provisioning Profile: also done via Apple Dev Center.
3. Configure Parse App: Change Parse settings, then upload the cert you created in step 1.
4. Configure App in Xcode: Change app to use provisioning profile you created in step 2.
5. Add Code to Prompt user for Notifications: write the code in your app that asks a user if they want to receive Push notifications, then store their device ID in Parse Installation class.
6. Send the Notification: as mentioned earlier this is the easiest step of all. It can be done via the Parse Dashboard (Click on Push notifications when looking at the Data Browser), via the Parse API or via Cloud-code. I did it via Cloud-Code and it looks like this:

   ```
   // Find the Installation (i.e. iOS Device) that belongs to my user*
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
   query.equalTo('user', user);
   Parse.Push.send({
       where: query, // Set our Installation query
       data: {
           alert: "This is the notification message",
           badge: "Increment"
       }
   }).then( function(){
       console.log("Push notification successfully sent!");
   });
   ```

   *I added a field in my installation class that captures a user. That way I know which device belongs to which user and can send targeted Push Notifications.
7. Prepare for Release: When you release your app, you will need to do some additional configuration to get everything ready to release.

Again, I recommend the Parse Docs. They are comprehensive and very helpful.  Let me know if you have any additional questions. Hope this helps!

** BTW: If you don't have any experience with cloud-code, then you can complete steps 1-5, then manually send the notifications via the Parse Dashboard.